# How to alternate in a table cell background color in each row and column

Tags: css

I'd like to format a CSS  as shown in the image: In odd rows the first column cell and in even rows the second column cell should be formatted with a different background color.

[image: example table]

I know how to alternate a whole row or column like

```
tr {
border-top: 0px solid $input-border-col;
&:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
&:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC;}
}
```

but haven't found a way how to alternate in each row

Comment: Show the code that you tried so far.

Comment: re-edited my post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `odd` and `even` CSS pseudo names.

Like this it does not matter how many `<tr>` or `<td>` your `<table>` will have.

```css
td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd),
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `nth-child` selector with `first/last child` to get desired result. So you can select all `tr` with `2n + 1` or odd rows and select first `td` and then select `tr` with `2n + 2` or even rows and select last `td`

```css
td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:nth-child(2n + 1) td:first-child,
tr:nth-child(2n + 2) td:last-child {
  background: #EA9999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following rule:

```
tr {
    &:nth-child(odd) {
        >td {
            &:nth-child(odd) {
                background-color: red;
            }
            &:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: white;
            }
        }
    }
    &:nth-child(even) {
        >td {
            &:nth-child(odd) {
                background-color: white;
            }
            &:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```